# VB POST REQUEST

Tags: vb.net, api

I am having different problems when trying to make a POST request to my API, the API works perfectly tested in postman.

I would like to know if anyone sees that I am doing wrong, thank you very much

```
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://0.0.0.0/connect")
    request.Method = "POST"

    Dim postData As String = "client_id=1&client_secret=F&grant_type=password&username=usuario&password=123&scope=Profile offline_access PaymentBO&provider=PersonalOld"
    Dim postdatabytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    response.Close()
    Return responseFromServer
```

The api responds to me (attached image)

[image: Response from API]

Comment: Please post actual text (not images of text).  In this case, although we can reasonably understand the meaning, it's still Spanish text in an otherwise English post so people might want to drop it into a translator.  Since the error points to specific lines of code in 2 different files, can you point out those lines?

Comment: Sorry technonaut the error comes on     Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()